# Error exporting calendar entries to an ics file

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Have an employee who is retiring. Trying to export his (very very numerous) calendar entries to ICS file and import to his google calendar. Worked fine on mine calendar, not with his. Certain entries seem to wipe out the entire download to the ics. ICS file has zero k. Calendar corrupt? Anybody heard of something like this?

Maybe I should run fixup and updaall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the file was corrupt. I made a new copy of the database and this fixed the corruption and allowed the export to work.